# Rails unit testing: can't get edit path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I'm following The Ruby on Rails by Michael Hart. In chapter 10, I'm getting unexpected errors when running unit tests.
This is my error:

> ERROR UsersControllerTest#test_should_redirect_edit_when_not_logged_in (1.01s)
> Minitest::UnexpectedError:         ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}, missing required keys: [:id]
> test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:16:in `block in class:UsersControllerTest'

This is my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    root "static_pages#home"
    get "/help", to: "static_pages#help"
    get "/about", to: "static_pages#about"
    get "/contact", to: "static_pages#contact"
    get "/signup", to: "users#new"
    get "/login", to: "sessions#new"
    post "/login", to: "sessions#create"
    delete "/logout", to: "sessions#destroy"
    resources :users
  end
end
```

This is my code in user_contrller_test

```
require "test_helper"

class UsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  
  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
    @other_user = users(:archer)
  end
  
  test "should get new" do
    get signup_path
    assert_response :success
  end
  
  test "should redirect edit when not logged in" do
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end
end
```

I've defined Michael in fixtures. I try to use path like `get :edit, user_id: @user.id` but it's still an error. I've run the server and access URLs like "/user/765/edit", it's successfully redirecting to the login URL.

How can I fix those.

Comment: i think `@user.id` is nil

Comment: I've debugged, @user.id still has value, like "762146111".

Answer (score 0):

you setup `resources :users` inside a scope `locale` in `routes` so that the path should be something like this `/en/users/1111/edit`

so in your test cases, you should call

```rb
get edit_user_path(:en, @user)
```

Comment: Thank u so much!!. I've passed the test ~. You save my night.